# Прослушай - заслушать

Tags: морфемный-разбор, приставка

Диктор по радио говорит: "Вы прослушали фрагмент Лунной сонаты Бетховена", но при этом, когда речь идет об официозе, то — "На заседании депутаты заслушали проект закона". Приставка *за-* может употребляться и для придания слову ироничного оттенка, например: "Зацени, какую я программу поставил".

Так что же именно придаёт слову приставка *за-*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае приставка указывает на результативность формального действия, которое ограничено во времени (здесь - конечностью "зачитываемого" доклада). Формально может потребоваться "заслушать" доклад или показания свидетелей; "зачитываемые" публично выдержки из документа и т.п. Факт "заслушивания" показаний в суде может быть "зафиксирован", "запротоколирован" и "зарегистрирован" (и здесь приставка указывает на результативность). Неформальные примеры с таким же значение приставки: записать, запомнить. Подобные глаголы могут быть как совершенного (зарегистрировать), так и несовершенного вида (записывать), в зависимости от однократного (завершённого) или длительного характера обозначаемого ими действия. Например, можно "записывать" (в процессе действия имеет место прогресс - оно результативно, не будучи завершённым) и "записать" (законченный результат).
Здесь отмечены 6 разных значений приставки "за" в глаголах:
http://slovotolk.ru/z2.html

Answer (score 2):

Приставка *за-* : это такой крючок, чтобы цеплять и *захватывать*.
[image: Багор]
<sub>(источник: [energoportal.ru](http://www.energoportal.ru/uploaded/images/16319-67308.jpeg))</sub>
Если попался кто, уже не уйдет... Заманят, завлекут, засмеют, задавят, замнут, забьют, затопчут - забияки, задаваки - заблудших и заплутавших.

> А. К. Толстой. Князь Серебряный (1842-1862)
> Перед ним стоял детина со всклокоченной бородой, с широким ножом за поясом и готовился попотчевать его новым ударом кулака.
> ― **Не замай!** ― сказал ему другой дюжий парень, у которого только что ус пробивался, ― что он тябе сделал?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае приставка указывает на результативность формального действия, которое ограничено во времени (здесь - конечностью "зачитываемого" доклада). Формально может потребоваться "заслушать" доклад или показания свидетелей; "зачитываемые" публично выдержки из документа и т.п. Факт "заслушивания" показаний в суде может быть "зафиксирован", "запротоколирован" и "зарегистрирован" (и здесь приставка указывает на результативность). Неформальные примеры с таким же значение приставки: записать, запомнить. Подобные глаголы могут быть как совершенного (зарегистрировать), так и несовершенного вида (записывать), в зависимости от однократного (завершённого) или длительного характера обозначаемого ими действия. Например, можно "записывать" (в процессе действия имеет место прогресс - оно результативно, не будучи завершённым) и "записать" (законченный результат).
Здесь отмечены 6 разных значений приставки "за" в глаголах:
http://slovotolk.ru/z2.html

Answer (score 0):

Слово "зацени" появилось буквально лет 15-20 назад, это чисто молодежный сленг — как пришло, так и уйдет. Не оно первое, не оно последнее. Так что приставка ЗА никакого ироничного оттенка слову не придает.